# Text color bug after installing OS X Theme

Tags: themes, files

I have installed macOS Sierra Theme by B00merang. There is a text colour bug when I right click in the file manager for more options of a file or a folder the texts appear white instead of black. I have seeked through the css files of the theme but I couldn't located the solution in there. The texts appears like in the following image

[image: Light Theme]

My temporary solution for this issue was using the dark variant option in the tweaks' theme menu, which is usable but this issue really bugs me. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this issue ? The dark variant option looks like the following

[image: Dark Variant]

PS: I use Loki 0.4 and I am a newbie to forum I am sorry if I have violated any rules.

Comment: You should ask the creator of this theme, it's clearly not an bug thats is caused by elementary OS.

Comment: I have sent them a mail. I will post here the solution

Comment: @Rafael That may be so, but I don't think that excludes the question from being valid.

Comment: I have contacted Christian Medel one of the people from B00merang project. He stated that he still couldn't find a solution for this weird behavior. I will update the post if he suggests any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a while Christian Medel responded me that the issue was caused by the base code now they have uploaded a new version of it here is the link [Github link](https://codeload.github.com/B00merang-Project/macOS-Sierra/zip/master)